# wc_set_customer_auth_cookie in hook does not have effect in downstream woocommerce scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a WooCommerce plugin wherein I call `wc_set_customer_auth_cookie($user->ID)` in an init hook function and then in the same function call `wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url)`.

When I log `get_current_user_id()` in the code called by redirect (plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php) I get 0.

Shouldn't I expect to get the user ID I set up in my hook?